# If Contains Value Move To Last (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL 2008

I am executing a SELECT, and I am trying to move all records to the end of the collection if they contain a certain text. As an example:

```
Example Table
----------------------

ID  Text
1     x
2     y
3     z
```

How using the above table would one write a query for returning all records but putting the records where Text = 'X' at the end of the returned collection. This is just an example table my entries are much different.

Comment: What do you mean by returned collection? Do you mean you just want to order the results of your query? Just use a case expression in your order by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach with a `case` statement:

```
select id, text
from example
order by case when text = 'x' then 1 else 0 end
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b6d/1)